# setVisibility() doesn't refresh UI Android

Tags: android-layout, refresh, visibility

I have a SurfaceView with a LinearLayout which hides or shows if you click on the SurfaceView.
The problem is that the SurfaceView is not refreshed so if the setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) actually doesn't work.

This is the code I'm using:

```
sv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Log.d("MainActivity-onCreate-onClick-buttons",
                        buttonsVisibility.toString());
                if (buttonsVisibility)
                {
                    linearLayoutButtons.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    buttonsVisibility = false;
                } else
                {
                    linearLayoutButtons.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    buttonsVisibility = true;
                }

            }
        });
```

By default buttonVisibility is set to false and the first time I click the view it actually is so so the logic is consistent, the only problem is that the setVisibility seems to have no effect. Only if I turn on/off the screen I can see the layout displayed correctly and then working properly. Why I need to turn the screen off to refresh the UI? Shouldn't it refresh automatically after the setVisibility?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but if I change my Buttons to be ImageButtons it works but buttons appear with a wrong "z-index" wherever I put them. I need to click once on them to fix the "z-index". If I change setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE) with setVisibility(View.GONE) all works fine.

Hope this might be helpful for someone with the same problem.